# Python 2.7 using nltk built-in dataset to do sentiment analysis for KNN

Tags: python-2.7, knn

As I am new to programming, I wish to know that is it possible to use the nltk built-in movie review dataset to do sentiment analysis by using KNN to determine the polarity of data? Is there any way to do so?

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]


all_words = []

for w in movie_reviews.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

def find_features(document):
    words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

    return features

featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

training_set = featuresets[500:1500]
testing_set = featuresets[:1500]

classifier = nltk.DecisionTreeClassifier.train(training_set)

print "Classifier accuracy percent:",(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100 , "%"

string = raw_input("Enter the string: ")
print (classifier.classify(find_features(word_tokenize(string))))
```

As I am trying to convert the code above from decision-tree to KNN

Comment: Yes. It is possible. You start by writing some code...

Comment: I tried to convert but fail from the code above (I edited my question)